# Beginner's Question about accessing mysql using OOP

Tags: php, mysql

I am reading the PHP and mySQL web development book and so far been doing all the PHP and mysql using procedural. But then it talks about accessing mysql with objects.

```
This works for me:
//I define $db so can connect
$query="select * FROM testing";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  //echo the data
}

But when I try to do it with classes, it doesn't
@ $db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "ERROR:";
exit;
}
$query="select * FROM testing";
$result=$db->query($query);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

Do I have to write my own class so it defines what query and fetch_assoc does? Or what?

Comment: Yes and could you show us how you are setting up $db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting up `$db` something like this:

```
$db = new mysqli("db_server", "db_username", "db_password", "db_name");
```

Comment: doing it OOP doesn't require me to write a class does it? Am I to assume that $result=$db->query($query); will know what -> does?

Comment: The `mysqli` class should already exist, and it should connect when constructed. It looks like your syntax is correct, which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I'm running 5.3.1. It seems when I use fetch_row($result) it throws an error, but when I use fetch_assoc() it works. Btw, thanks for your help!